# 'All' or 'everyone'- which one fits better here?

Tags: pronouns, phrase-choice

'God bless you' or 'God bless America' is a very common phrase to hear. But yesterday I read a sentence saying: 'God bless ***everyone***'.

IMO, '**all**' fits here more than '**everyone**' as it includes every creature. I consider that 'everyone' is used for humans only. Am I right?

Comment: What was the context of the sentence? The phrase is OK though and should refer to people. There is the famous Tiny Tim line in "A Christmas Carol" - "God Bless Us, Everyone."

Comment: @user3169 I want to know which pronoun is preferable for this phrase- all or everyone? If we say, 'God bless everyone', then we're talking about humans only, right? Therefore, IMO, 'God bless all' looks more precise. I want your take on this.

Comment: Where is it being said/written?

Answer (score 1):

**Everyone** refers to people, **everything** refers to both animate and inanimate.

> God bless **everyone**
>   God bless **us** all

maybe **ambiguous** since the criteria for **everyone** is not stated. Is it

> Everyone in the world?
>   Everyone in our community?
>   Everyone in our country?
>   Everyone in our social group?
>   Everyone in our group that is praying?

> God bless us **each and every one**

Would mean everyone present at the gathering when the prayer is said.

> God bless **all creatures great and small**

Could be used, it is also the title of a hymn